# Having different relationships to the same table in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have the following scenario. There are Authors and Courses entities with One-To-Many relationship from Author to Courses. Then I have Students and Enrollments entities, the latter being the join column for Many-to-Many relationship between Students and Courses entities.

Now, instead of two Entities, Authors and Students I would like to have one entity, let's call it Accounts. In this case, I am having one account_id field in Courses entity being used in two relationships. This is giving me an error, but for me, it seems to be a valid case.
The error is JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by adding

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
```

On the Accounts entity. The rest is left intact.